FFMpeg fails to compile
I'm trying to compile a project that needs a specific version of ffmpeg to work.
I isolated ffmpeg build and tried to compile it on its own as done in the parent project.
It seems to be version 6.1.1, the build system downloads ffmpeg from this url https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/archive/e38092ef9395d7049f871ef4d5411eb410e283e0.zip before building it.
I'm using an up-to-date debian testing distribution.
When trying to build it on my own, I got this error message:
$ ./configure --enable-shared --disable-static --disable-programs --disable-doc
$ make
CC  libavcodec/vulkan_av1.o
In file included from libavcodec/vulkan_av1.c:21:
libavcodec/vulkan_decode.h:31:5: error: unknown type name ‘VkVideoDecodeAV1ProfileInfoMESA’
   31 |     VkVideoDecodeAV1ProfileInfoMESA av1_profile;
      |     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
libavcodec/vulkan_av1.c:38:5: error: unknown type name ‘StdVideoAV1MESATile’
   38 |     StdVideoAV1MESATile            tiles[MAX_TILES];
      |     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
libavcodec/vulkan_av1.c:39:5: error: unknown type name ‘StdVideoAV1MESATileList’
   39 |     StdVideoAV1MESATileList        tile_list;
      |     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
libavcodec/vulkan_av1.c:43:5: error: unknown type name ‘VkVideoDecodeAV1DpbSlotInfoMESA’
   43 |     VkVideoDecodeAV1DpbSlotInfoMESA    vkav1_ref;
      |     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
libavcodec/vulkan_av1.c:44:5: error: unknown type name ‘StdVideoAV1MESAFrameHeader’
   44 |     StdVideoAV1MESAFrameHeader         av1_frame_header;
      |     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
libavcodec/vulkan_av1.c:45:5: error: unknown type name ‘VkVideoDecodeAV1PictureInfoMESA’
   45 |     VkVideoDecodeAV1PictureInfoMESA    av1_pic_info;
      |     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
libavcodec/vulkan_av1.c:49:5: error: unknown type name ‘VkVideoDecodeAV1DpbSlotInfoMESA’
   49 |     VkVideoDecodeAV1DpbSlotInfoMESA     vkav1_refs[AV1_NUM_REF_FRAMES];
      |     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
libavcodec/vulkan_av1.c:58:29: error: unknown type name ‘VkVideoDecodeAV1DpbSlotInfoMESA’; did you mean ‘VkVideoDecodeAV1DpbSlotInfoKHR’?
   58 |                             VkVideoDecodeAV1DpbSlotInfoMESA *vkav1_ref, /* Goes in ^ */
      |                             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                             VkVideoDecodeAV1DpbSlotInfoKHR
libavcodec/vulkan_av1.c: In function ‘vk_av1_create_params’:
libavcodec/vulkan_av1.c:113:5: error: unknown type name ‘StdVideoAV1MESASequenceHeader’; did you mean ‘StdVideoAV1SequenceHeader’?
  113 |     StdVideoAV1MESASequenceHeader av1_sequence_header;
      |     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |     StdVideoAV1SequenceHeader
libavcodec/vulkan_av1.c:114:5: error: unknown type name ‘VkVideoDecodeAV1SessionParametersAddInfoMESA’; did you mean ‘VkVideoDecodeH265SessionParametersAddInfoKHR’?
  114 |     VkVideoDecodeAV1SessionParametersAddInfoMESA av1_params_info;
      |     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |     VkVideoDecodeH265SessionParametersAddInfoKHR
libavcodec/vulkan_av1.c:115:5: error: unknown type name ‘VkVideoDecodeAV1SessionParametersCreateInfoMESA’; did you mean ‘VkVideoDecodeAV1SessionParametersCreateInfoKHR’?
  115 |     VkVideoDecodeAV1SessionParametersCreateInfoMESA av1_params;
      |     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |     VkVideoDecodeAV1SessionParametersCreateInfoKHR
libavcodec/vulkan_av1.c:120:28: error: ‘StdVideoAV1MESASequenceHeader’ undeclared (first use in this function); did you mean ‘StdVideoAV1SequenceHeader’?
  120 |     av1_sequence_header = (StdVideoAV1MESASequenceHeader) {
      |                            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                            StdVideoAV1SequenceHeader
libavcodec/vulkan_av1.c:120:28: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
libavcodec/vulkan_av1.c:120:58: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘{’ token
  120 |     av1_sequence_header = (StdVideoAV1MESASequenceHeader) {
      |                                                          ^~
      |                                                          ;
libavcodec/vulkan_av1.c:171:24: error: ‘VkVideoDecodeAV1SessionParametersAddInfoMESA’ undeclared (first use in this function); did you mean ‘VkVideoDecodeH265SessionParametersAddInfoKHR’?
  171 |     av1_params_info = (VkVideoDecodeAV1SessionParametersAddInfoMESA) {
      |                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                        VkVideoDecodeH265SessionParametersAddInfoKHR
libavcodec/vulkan_av1.c:171:69: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘{’ token
  171 |     av1_params_info = (VkVideoDecodeAV1SessionParametersAddInfoMESA) {
      |                                                                     ^~
      |                                                                     ;
libavcodec/vulkan_av1.c:175:19: error: ‘VkVideoDecodeAV1SessionParametersCreateInfoMESA’ undeclared (first use in this function); did you mean ‘VkVideoDecodeAV1SessionParametersCreateInfoKHR’?
  175 |     av1_params = (VkVideoDecodeAV1SessionParametersCreateInfoMESA) {
      |                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                   VkVideoDecodeAV1SessionParametersCreateInfoKHR
libavcodec/vulkan_av1.c:175:67: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘{’ token
  175 |     av1_params = (VkVideoDecodeAV1SessionParametersCreateInfoMESA) {
      |                                                                   ^~
      |                                                                   ;
libavcodec/vulkan_av1.c:114:50: warning: variable ‘av1_params_info’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
  114 |     VkVideoDecodeAV1SessionParametersAddInfoMESA av1_params_info;
      |                                                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
libavcodec/vulkan_av1.c:113:35: warning: variable ‘av1_sequence_header’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
  113 |     StdVideoAV1MESASequenceHeader av1_sequence_header;
      |                                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
libavcodec/vulkan_av1.c:111:33: warning: unused variable ‘seq’ [-Wunused-variable]
  111 |     const AV1RawSequenceHeader *seq = s->raw_seq;
      |                                 ^~~
libavcodec/vulkan_av1.c: In function ‘vk_av1_start_frame’:
libavcodec/vulkan_av1.c:237:15: error: implicit declaration of function ‘vk_av1_fill_pict’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
  237 |         err = vk_av1_fill_pict(avctx, &ap->ref_src[i], &vp->ref_slots[i],
      |               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
libavcodec/vulkan_av1.c:252:18: error: request for member ‘nb_tiles’ in something not a structure or union
  252 |     ap->tile_list.nb_tiles = 0;
      |                  ^
libavcodec/vulkan_av1.c:253:18: error: request for member ‘tile_list’ in something not a structure or union
  253 |     ap->tile_list.tile_list = ap->tiles;
      |                  ^
libavcodec/vulkan_av1.c:255:25: error: ‘VkVideoDecodeAV1PictureInfoMESA’ undeclared (first use in this function); did you mean ‘VkVideoDecodeAV1PictureInfoKHR’?
  255 |     ap->av1_pic_info = (VkVideoDecodeAV1PictureInfoMESA) {
      |                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                         VkVideoDecodeAV1PictureInfoKHR
libavcodec/vulkan_av1.c:255:57: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘{’ token
  255 |     ap->av1_pic_info = (VkVideoDecodeAV1PictureInfoMESA) {
      |                                                         ^~
      |                                                         ;
libavcodec/vulkan_av1.c:278:29: error: ‘StdVideoAV1MESAFrameHeader’ undeclared (first use in this function); did you mean ‘StdVideoAV1SequenceHeader’?
  278 |     ap->av1_frame_header = (StdVideoAV1MESAFrameHeader) {
      |                             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                             StdVideoAV1SequenceHeader
libavcodec/vulkan_av1.c:278:56: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘{’ token
  278 |     ap->av1_frame_header = (StdVideoAV1MESAFrameHeader) {
      |                                                        ^~
      |                                                        ;
libavcodec/vulkan_av1.c:402:29: error: request for member ‘tiling’ in something not a structure or union
  402 |         ap->av1_frame_header.tiling.width_in_sbs_minus_1[i] = frame_header->width_in_sbs_minus_1[i];
      |                             ^
libavcodec/vulkan_av1.c:403:29: error: request for member ‘tiling’ in something not a structure or union
  403 |         ap->av1_frame_header.tiling.height_in_sbs_minus_1[i] = frame_header->height_in_sbs_minus_1[i];
      |                             ^
libavcodec/vulkan_av1.c:404:29: error: request for member ‘tiling’ in something not a structure or union
  404 |         ap->av1_frame_header.tiling.tile_start_col_sb[i] = frame_header->tile_start_col_sb[i];
      |                             ^
libavcodec/vulkan_av1.c:405:29: error: request for member ‘tiling’ in something not a structure or union
  405 |         ap->av1_frame_header.tiling.tile_start_row_sb[i] = frame_header->tile_start_row_sb[i];
      |                             ^
libavcodec/vulkan_av1.c:409:29: error: request for member ‘segmentation’ in something not a structure or union
  409 |         ap->av1_frame_header.segmentation.feature_enabled_bits[i] = 0;
      |                             ^
libavcodec/vulkan_av1.c:411:33: error: request for member ‘segmentation’ in something not a structure or union
  411 |             ap->av1_frame_header.segmentation.feature_enabled_bits[i] |= (frame_header->feature_enabled[i][j] << j);
      |                                 ^
libavcodec/vulkan_av1.c:412:33: error: request for member ‘segmentation’ in something not a structure or union
  412 |             ap->av1_frame_header.segmentation.feature_data[i][j] = frame_header->feature_value[i][j];
      |                                 ^
libavcodec/vulkan_av1.c:415:29: error: request for member ‘loop_filter’ in something not a structure or union
  415 |         ap->av1_frame_header.loop_filter.ref_deltas[i] = frame_header->loop_filter_ref_deltas[i];
      |                             ^
libavcodec/vulkan_av1.c:417:29: error: request for member ‘cdef’ in something not a structure or union
  417 |         ap->av1_frame_header.cdef.y_pri_strength[i] = frame_header->cdef_y_pri_strength[i];
      |                             ^
libavcodec/vulkan_av1.c:418:29: error: request for member ‘cdef’ in something not a structure or union
  418 |         ap->av1_frame_header.cdef.y_sec_strength[i] = frame_header->cdef_y_sec_strength[i];
      |                             ^
libavcodec/vulkan_av1.c:419:29: error: request for member ‘cdef’ in something not a structure or union
  419 |         ap->av1_frame_header.cdef.uv_pri_strength[i] = frame_header->cdef_uv_pri_strength[i];
      |                             ^
libavcodec/vulkan_av1.c:420:29: error: request for member ‘cdef’ in something not a structure or union
  420 |         ap->av1_frame_header.cdef.uv_sec_strength[i] = frame_header->cdef_uv_sec_strength[i];
      |                             ^
libavcodec/vulkan_av1.c:422:29: error: request for member ‘ref_order_hint’ in something not a structure or union
  422 |         ap->av1_frame_header.ref_order_hint[i] = frame_header->ref_order_hint[i];
      |                             ^
libavcodec/vulkan_av1.c:423:29: error: request for member ‘global_motion’ in something not a structure or union
  423 |         ap->av1_frame_header.global_motion[i] = (StdVideoAV1MESAGlobalMotion) {
      |                             ^
libavcodec/vulkan_av1.c:423:50: error: ‘StdVideoAV1MESAGlobalMotion’ undeclared (first use in this function); did you mean ‘StdVideoAV1GlobalMotion’?
  423 |         ap->av1_frame_header.global_motion[i] = (StdVideoAV1MESAGlobalMotion) {
      |                                                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                                                  StdVideoAV1GlobalMotion
libavcodec/vulkan_av1.c:423:78: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘{’ token
  423 |         ap->av1_frame_header.global_motion[i] = (StdVideoAV1MESAGlobalMotion) {
      |                                                                              ^~
      |                                                                              ;
libavcodec/vulkan_av1.c:437:29: error: request for member ‘ref_frame_idx’ in something not a structure or union
  437 |         ap->av1_frame_header.ref_frame_idx[i] = frame_header->ref_frame_idx[i];
      |                             ^
libavcodec/vulkan_av1.c:438:29: error: request for member ‘delta_frame_id_minus1’ in something not a structure or union
  438 |         ap->av1_frame_header.delta_frame_id_minus1[i] = frame_header->delta_frame_id_minus1[i];
      |                             ^
libavcodec/vulkan_av1.c:441:21: error: request for member ‘skip_mode_frame_idx’ in something not a structure or union
  441 |     ap->av1_pic_info.skip_mode_frame_idx[0] = s->cur_frame.skip_mode_frame_idx[0];
      |                     ^
libavcodec/vulkan_av1.c:442:21: error: request for member ‘skip_mode_frame_idx’ in something not a structure or union
  442 |     ap->av1_pic_info.skip_mode_frame_idx[1] = s->cur_frame.skip_mode_frame_idx[1];
      |                     ^
libavcodec/vulkan_av1.c:446:33: error: request for member ‘film_grain’ in something not a structure or union
  446 |             ap->av1_frame_header.film_grain.point_y_value[i] = film_grain->point_y_value[i];
      |                                 ^
libavcodec/vulkan_av1.c:447:33: error: request for member ‘film_grain’ in something not a structure or union
  447 |             ap->av1_frame_header.film_grain.point_y_scaling[i] = film_grain->point_y_scaling[i];
      |                                 ^
libavcodec/vulkan_av1.c:451:33: error: request for member ‘film_grain’ in something not a structure or union
  451 |             ap->av1_frame_header.film_grain.point_cb_value[i] = film_grain->point_cb_value[i];
      |                                 ^
libavcodec/vulkan_av1.c:452:33: error: request for member ‘film_grain’ in something not a structure or union
  452 |             ap->av1_frame_header.film_grain.point_cb_scaling[i] = film_grain->point_cb_scaling[i];
      |                                 ^
libavcodec/vulkan_av1.c:453:33: error: request for member ‘film_grain’ in something not a structure or union
  453 |             ap->av1_frame_header.film_grain.point_cr_value[i] = film_grain->point_cr_value[i];
      |                                 ^
libavcodec/vulkan_av1.c:454:33: error: request for member ‘film_grain’ in something not a structure or union
  454 |             ap->av1_frame_header.film_grain.point_cr_scaling[i] = film_grain->point_cr_scaling[i];
      |                                 ^
libavcodec/vulkan_av1.c:458:33: error: request for member ‘film_grain’ in something not a structure or union
  458 |             ap->av1_frame_header.film_grain.ar_coeffs_y_plus_128[i] = film_grain->ar_coeffs_y_plus_128[i];
      |                                 ^
libavcodec/vulkan_av1.c:459:33: error: request for member ‘film_grain’ in something not a structure or union
  459 |             ap->av1_frame_header.film_grain.ar_coeffs_cb_plus_128[i] = film_grain->ar_coeffs_cb_plus_128[i];
      |                                 ^
libavcodec/vulkan_av1.c:460:33: error: request for member ‘film_grain’ in something not a structure or union
  460 |             ap->av1_frame_header.film_grain.ar_coeffs_cr_plus_128[i] = film_grain->ar_coeffs_cr_plus_128[i];
      |                                 ^
libavcodec/vulkan_av1.c:463:29: error: request for member ‘film_grain’ in something not a structure or union
  463 |         ap->av1_frame_header.film_grain.ar_coeffs_cb_plus_128[24] = film_grain->ar_coeffs_cb_plus_128[24];
      |                             ^
libavcodec/vulkan_av1.c:464:29: error: request for member ‘film_grain’ in something not a structure or union
  464 |         ap->av1_frame_header.film_grain.ar_coeffs_cr_plus_128[24] = film_grain->ar_coeffs_cr_plus_128[24];
      |                             ^
libavcodec/vulkan_av1.c: In function ‘vk_av1_decode_slice’:
libavcodec/vulkan_av1.c:483:32: error: request for member ‘nb_tiles’ in something not a structure or union
  483 |         ap->tiles[ap->tile_list.nb_tiles] = (StdVideoAV1MESATile) {
      |                                ^
libavcodec/vulkan_av1.c:483:46: error: ‘StdVideoAV1MESATile’ undeclared (first use in this function); did you mean ‘StdVideoAV1Profile’?
  483 |         ap->tiles[ap->tile_list.nb_tiles] = (StdVideoAV1MESATile) {
      |                                              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                                              StdVideoAV1Profile
libavcodec/vulkan_av1.c:483:66: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘{’ token
  483 |         ap->tiles[ap->tile_list.nb_tiles] = (StdVideoAV1MESATile) {
      |                                                                  ^~
      |                                                                  ;
libavcodec/vulkan_av1.c:495:52: error: request for member ‘nb_tiles’ in something not a structure or union
  495 |                                      &ap->tile_list.nb_tiles,
      |                                                    ^
libavcodec/vulkan_av1.c:500:32: error: request for member ‘nb_tiles’ in something not a structure or union
  500 |         ap->tiles[ap->tile_list.nb_tiles - 1].offset = ap->tile_offsets[ap->tile_list.nb_tiles - 1];
      |                                ^
libavcodec/vulkan_av1.c:500:86: error: request for member ‘nb_tiles’ in something not a structure or union
  500 |         ap->tiles[ap->tile_list.nb_tiles - 1].offset = ap->tile_offsets[ap->tile_list.nb_tiles - 1];
      |                                                                                      ^
libavcodec/vulkan_av1.c: In function ‘vk_av1_end_frame’:
libavcodec/vulkan_av1.c:516:23: error: request for member ‘nb_tiles’ in something not a structure or union
  516 |     if (!ap->tile_list.nb_tiles)
      |                       ^
libavcodec/vulkan_av1.c:534:42: error: request for member ‘nb_tiles’ in something not a structure or union
  534 |            vp->slices_size, ap->tile_list.nb_tiles);
      |                                          ^
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
make: *** [ffbuild/common.mak:81: libavcodec/vulkan_av1.o] Error 1

The command launch above are the one taken from the parent app build system.
I'm not familiar with ffmpeg or graphics system in general.
I don't understand why the first message says that VkVideoDecodeAV1ProfileInfoMESA could not be found.
I thought I might be missing some package dependencies but it appears that a VkVideoDecodeAV1ProfileInfoMESA typedef can be found in ffmpeg sources (libavcodec/vulkan_video_codec_av1std.h:373 in this version).
So I assume something may be wrong with my compile configuration ?
I'm a little bit lost on this issue and don't know what to look for to solve it.

What do you mean by Trixie/Sid? Are you on Trixie or on Sid? Or are you saying you are on Trixie but you have some packages from Sid? (Which ones?)

I'm on testing. I've copy pasted the result of /etc/issue, my bad.

Common lore tells us that to build any given software, you do ./configure; make; make install.
Unfortunately this knowledge has descended to us from the golden days, building simple server-side software with a rather limited (or even no) dependency stack. Alas! those days are gone.
Guaranteeing for a given piece of software that it can be compiled on an arbitrary environment, is a non-trivial task.
Debian packagers (<rantㅤ>conversely to what many people seem to believe, packaging any given piece of software is actually work</rantㅤ>) usually take care of these quirks, by

making sure all the required (and available) dependencies are installed: https://salsa.debian.org/multimedia-team/ffmpeg/-/blob/debian/7%256.1.1-4/debian/control#L15-L202
the package is called with the correct configure/build options: https://salsa.debian.org/multimedia-team/ffmpeg/-/blob/debian/7%256.1.1-4/debian/rules
if all things fail, the source code might be patched
https://salsa.debian.org/multimedia-team/ffmpeg/-/tree/debian/7%256.1.1-4/debian/patches

So the first thing you want to make sure, is that all dependencies are installed. Luckily this is super-easy and can be done with a simple
apt-get build-dep ffmpeg

If this doesn't help, you probably have to mimic the other two steps from the Debian packaging (as referenced above), which is coniderably harder, and would involve patching your parent project's buildsystem. (If you've isolated the build, then this is of course rather easy)
